# Use javascript to change background css on browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, background-size

So, I want the background-size to change when the browser height is equal to 2/3 of the browser width. Here is the code I've tried, and I can't get it to work.

```
<body id="body" onresize="BG_resize()">
<script>
    function BG_resize() {
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        var h = window.innerHeight;

        if ((w * (2 / 3)) < h){
            document.getElementById("body").style.background-size = "auto 100%";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

The css:

```
#body {
    background:url("Layout/BG.jpg");
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative to all of these is to use media queries (since you're doing this on the window) and get rid of the javascript all together. This will run smoother as the browser does most of the work for you.

Looks like the query you are looking for is the aspect-ratio so something like:

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 2/3) 
{
   body {
      background-size: auto 100%;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 2/3) 
{
   body {
      background-size: 100% auto;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JS should use backgroundSize, not background-size:

```
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundSize = "auto 100%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which I find easier is using jQuery. You can simply use the resize() event handler. Below is an example:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
```

//Here you can add your code that you want to execute on resize
})

To then change the css you can also use jQuery .css().

Answer (score 0):

http://fofwebdesign.co.uk/template/_...tio-resize.htm

```css
.target-ratio-resize {
 max-width: 960px; /* actual img width */
 max-height: 150px; /* actual img height */
 *height: 150px; /* actual img height - IE7 */
 background-image: url(students.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}
.target-ratio-resize:after {
 content: " ";
 display: block; 
 width: 100%; 
 padding-top: 66.666%; /* 2:3 ratio */
}
```